# Getting stack trace from Python core dump?

Tags: python, signals, kill, sigabrt, coredump

I have a Python process that hangs. However, when I kill it, it does not write to `stdout` or `stderr`, which prevents me from being able to debug it by reading the stack trace. I can get a core dump with `SIGABRT` - is there a way to get the stack trace from the core dump?

Comment: I'm aware that I can use gdb w/ Python extensions to get the trace - but my machine may not support them.

Comment: Why wouldn't your machine support them?